# Widget development - Drop down options won't save

Tags: plugin-development, widgets

So, i successfully managed to add a drop down option, the problem is when i click save all of the options are removed, however the chosen option is implemented successfully.

Here is the relevant code:

```
function widget($args, $instance) {
        extract( $args );

        $pfxattribution = $instance['pfx-attribution'];
}

<p>
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('pfx-attribution'); ?>"><?php _e('Choose attribution:'); ?></label>
            <select id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('pfx-attribution'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('pfx-attribution'); ?>" class="widefat" /> 
            <option>Purefx</option>
            <option>Foreign Exchange</option>
            <option>Currency Exchange</option>
            </select>
            </p>

function update($new_instance, $old_instance) {
        // Get the old values
        $instance = $old_instance;

        // Update with any new values (and sanitise input)
        $instance['pfx-attribution'] = strip_tags( $new_instance['pfx-attribution'] );

       return $instance;
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Danny, this is pretty much lifted straight from a plug-in I've made:

```
 <?php function form($instance){    
    $instance = wp_parse_args( (array) $instance, $this->w_arg );
  ?>
  <p>
    <select id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('order'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('order'); ?>" type="text">
        <option value="asc" <?php selected($instance['order'], 'asc'); ?>>ASC </option>
        <option value="desc" <?php selected($instance['order'], 'desc');?>>DESC </option>
    </select>
</p>

<?php
  }
?>
```

Without seeing the rest of your code I can't be sure the root of the problem, but it could be the form is not wrapped inside the form function. If the above doesn't seem to work for you, perhaps pastie your Widget Class?

I should perhaps add that my widget class has a variable `w_arg`, an array of defaults! E.g.

```
var $w_arg = array(
        'order'=> 'ASC'
        );
```

Comment: Thanks for your input Stephen, it is wrapped correctly inside the form function, I also have a bunch of other plain text box options which are working flawlessly, I also have defaults defined in a very similar way to you. The problem appears to be specifically related to drop down options and check boxes!

Answer (score 0):

Your `<option>`s need `value=` or they do not send any value...essentially right now `value=''`, which is, I'd bet, what you're seeing.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, everything works perfectly until I hit save then all options disappear, sadly adding a 'value' to my options didn't make any difference. :-(

Comment: Well you also lack `selected()` calls...it should be in the DB now, you're just not pulling it when you load the box

Comment: Without a `value` attribute, an `option` will send its contents ([w3 ref](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.6)).

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up Geert. Thanks again mOr7if3r - I'm not familiar with selected() calls, I'll look it up now and see if that fixes anything. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Your `<select>` should not have a `value` attribute, nor the `type="text"` attribute.

Comment: Thanks Geert, very sloppy on my part! Sadly the options still disappear when i hit save...

Comment: Well, time to debug further then. Do a `var_dump()` of `$_POST` or `$new_instance`.